# Does my Sinatra API application need a class declaration?

Tags: ruby, nginx, logging, sinatra

Someone developed an API application for me that works well. Unfortunately, it doesn't log anywhere and there are no logs at all. The app runs with the "rackup" command and sits behind an nginx web server. The Sinatra errors are not logged to the nginx logs.

The `app.rb` file looks something like this:

```
require './libs'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'

set :bind, '::1'

before do
  content_type :json
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST']
end

namespace '/api/v1' do
  namespace '/getit/:thingtoget' do
    helpers do
      def myhelper1
        <stuff>
      end
      def myhelper1
        <stuff>
      end
   end

   before do
     myhelper1
     myhelper2
   end

   get '/info' do
     WidgetDomain::get_info(@va1, @var2).to_json
   end

   <more API paths here>

 end
```

Now this is working fine. But now I want to introduce logging. So I looked at the Sinatra README and it said I could enable logging like so:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure :production, :development do
    enable :logging
  end
end
```

Do I put that above the `namespace` stuff? If I declare an app like that, does my namespace stuff need to be inside that app code somehow? I don't have a grasp of how this works at all.

It almost looks like it's *trying* to log in the nginx log, but here's what an error line looks like there:

```
2018/12/30 19:53:15 [error] 6615#0: *21522 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <someip>, server: api.example.com, request: "GET /api/v1/getit/thingtoget1/stuff/var1/var2/var3 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:9292/api/v1/getit/thingtoget/stuff/var1/var2/var3", host: "api.example.com", referrer: "an HTML page from the nginx server"
```

It's almost like it's trying to connect back to the server to retrieve a message or something. But in case the logging has something to do with the way I've declared the server in the nginx configuration, here it is:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name api.myapp.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp_com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star_myapp_com.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9292;
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like a "top-level" Sinatra application, where logging is enabled by default, and is displayed in the console from which you started it. How do you start your Sinatra application?

Comment: bundle exec rackup config.ru -D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Sinatra's [README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro) in the Logging section but I tend to set up a logger outside of the Sinatra app in case other bits get bolted on or several apps are used together and I can use the same logger for all of them. Simplest way is a global variable (one of the few places they're acceptable, but it's not the only way) :

```
require 'mono_logger' # because it's thread safe
require 'pathname'    # because paths aren't strings :)

log_path = Pathname(__dir__).join("logs/app.log")
$logger = MonoLogger.new(log_path)
$logger.level = MonoLogger::INFO
```

Then in a route or wherever:

```
get '/' do
  $logger.info "here"
```

In my terminal:

```
$ cat logs/app.log 
I, [2019-01-07T13:03:52.989415 #64378]  INFO -- : here
```

As to configuration blocks, you don't need to worry about putting them within a class declaration unless you're using a modular app (see Modular vs. Classic Style in the README) and yours is in the classic style.

Configuration blocks aren't namespaced ([Sinatra::Namespace](http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/namespace.html) handles things that take a route as an argument, like `get` and `before`) so follow convention and stick it near the top of the file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @AKWF I put it either before the Sinatra app declaration(s) - if there's only one file then stick it at or near the top - or in the config.ru if there is one. Basically, somewhere in the chain of files near the beginning so that it's declared in time for anything that needs it to use it during start up.

Comment: @AKWF If they're the only files relating to the sinatra app, sure.